# ASP.Net ASOS JWT return Token but doesn't authorize

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, aspnet-contrib

I'm building a simple application with a fixed credential, so there's no need to integrate with EF or whatever.

I'm trying to use the AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server package with JWT configuration, I can validate my credentials and return the Token, but using [Authorize] attribute my endpoint always return 401 unauthorized.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
{
    options.AllowInsecureHttp = true;
    options.AccessTokenLifetime = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    options.TokenEndpointPath = "/v1/authtoken";
    options.AccessTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler
    {
        OutboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    };
    options.Provider = new AuthorizationProvider();
    options.SigningCredentials.AddKey(Key);
})
.AddJwtBearer();

....

app.UseAuthentication();
```

AuthorizationProvider.cs

```
public override Task HandleTokenRequest(HandleTokenRequestContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.IsClientCredentialsGrantType())
    {
        if (!string.Equals(context.Request.ClientId, "username", StringComparison.Ordinal) ||
            !string.Equals(context.Request.ClientSecret, "password, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            context.Reject(
                error: OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                description: "Invalid user credentials.");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Scheme.Name);

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject, "subject"));
        identity.AddClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user", OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken,
            OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken);

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
            new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
            new AuthenticationProperties(), context.Scheme.Name);
        ticket.SetResources("resource_server");

        context.Validate(ticket);
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = "user")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
```

According to jwt.io, this is the payload inside the JWT:

```
{
  "sub": "subject",
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "user",
  "token_usage": "access_token",
  "jti": "7b5d3180-b535-489b-97ec-fccaedf9615a",
  "cfd_lvl": "private",
  "aud": "resource_server",
  "azp": "username",
  "nbf": 1550510623,
  "exp": 1550514223,
  "iat": 1550510623,
  "iss": "https://localhost:44302/"
}
```

Also tried to use just `[Authorize]`, but I also get 401 unauthorized.

If I use the default ASOS Token, it work without any problem, just having problems when using JWT (Which I'm trying to use because I want to add a Custom Key and not a Certificate).

[Postman Request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMKJP.png)

Comment: How are you making your request once you've received a token? Are you adding the "access_token" value to your authentication request response as an Authorization header of `Bearer {token}`?

Comment: Yes, I'm always making the request with the `Authorization` Header with value `Bearer {token}`. Edited the main post with one image from postman.

Comment: Is "resource_server" configured as an allowed audience?

Comment: Yes I think so, I added the `options.TokenValidationParameters` with `ValidAudience = "resource_server",` in the `AddJwtBearer` configuration. Also tried to remove the SetResource when creating the token. Both methods failed.

Comment: Hard to say what's going on as you didn't post your JWT bearer options. Take a look at the ASP.NET Core logs, there's certainly something there that will help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: @Loeseeeeee you can try to set Validation fields to `'true'` or `'false'` from `'TokenValidationParameters'`  to understand what cause the problem.  
  
`ValidateIssuer = true` -> ASOS verify that the issuer is correct  
`ValidateAudience = true` -> ASOS verify that the audience is correct  
`ValidateLifetime = true` -> ASOS verify that the lifetime is correct  
  
When I use ASOS i also add SigningKeys to `'OpenIdConnectServer'` -> `'options.SigningCredentials.AddKey(your_symm_or_asym_key);'`

Comment: @Loeseeeeee You can also try to add `'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException'` under `'Exception Settings'` in VS to see the full error.

Example of error: `'IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: 'testaudience'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'null' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'audiencetest, testaud'`